# Form input text field is not working

Tags: spring, jsp

I have jsp file and trying to insert values from two text fields. i'm using `<form:input path="name" />` for input.but it's not showing text field when running (Image 1).

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="student">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter your name:</td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="name" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter your last name:</td>
                <td><form:input path="lastName" /></td>
                <td><form:errors path="lastName" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

Student Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/student.htm")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("studentValidator")
    private Validator validator;

    @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(validator);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initForm(Model model){
        Student student = new Student();
        model.addAttribute("student", student);
        return "student";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitForm(
        Model model, @Validated Student student, BindingResult result) {
        String returnVal = "success";
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            returnVal = "student";
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("student", student);
        }       
        return returnVal;
    }

}
```

Image 1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include this tag in your page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

Answer (score -1):

include taglib and send commandName (student) from your Controller for a form

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="student">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter your name:</td>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="name" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter your last name:</td>
            <td><form:input path="lastName" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="lastName" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

and in **@Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/")//your mapped path
public String indexPage(Model model){
   model.addAttribute("student",new Student());
   return "index";//your view Name
}

@PostMapping("/")
public String register(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student,BindingResult result){
 // your logic
}
```

Comment: i added `<%@taglib` and tested.now got 500 error (An exception occurred processing JSP page [/index.jsp] at line [12]). in line 12 show `<form:form method="POST" commandName="student">`

Comment: yes! your correct  you need to pass command name (student) from  your Controller

Comment: I have edited my post and i'm totally new for this.how do i pass commandname ?